# proplem in program by python fractions

Tags: class, fractions

```
i have error in my code that write by python about fractions but I fase me proplem.
```

The error is that I don't know how to ask the object
Save the variable value of Objet and then call the aldea that do the mathematical operatio
plese help me to correct it

---

Comment: Please clarify / rephrase your question. Add some code / whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: your question isn't clear. Please consider adding a code snippet, the precise error python is throwing at you, and what you tried to do

Answer (score -1):

```
 from fractions import*
 # for testing vlaues
 f12 = Fraction(1,2)
 f44 = Fraction(4,4)
 f128 = Fraction(12,8)
 f32 = Fraction(3,2)
 class Fraction:
 def __init__ (self, numerator, denominator):
    self.numerator = numerator
    self.denominator = denominator
    if self.denominator == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("sorry you are dividing by zero")

def sum(self, other):

    numerator = (self.numerator * other.denominator) + (self.denominator + 
other.numerator)
    denominator = (self.denominator * other.denominator)
    return Fraction(numerator/denominator)

def minus(self, other):
    numerator = (self.numerator * other.denominator) - (self.denominator + 
other.numerator)
    denominator = (self.denominator * other.denominator)
    return Fraction(numerator/denominator)

def times(self, other):

    numerator = self.numerator * other.numerator
    denominator = self.denominator * other.denominator
    return Fraction(numerator/denominator)

def divid (self, other):
    numerator = self.numerator * other.denominator
    denominator = self.denominator * other.numerator
    return Fraction(numerator/denominator)

def equals(self, other):

    return self.numerator * other.denominator == self.denominator * 
other.numerator

def test_suite(self,other):

    if self == f12:
       print(f"[{f12} + {f12} == {f12.sum(f12)} ] [4/4]")
    elif self == f44 and other == f12:
       print(f"[{f44} - {f12} == {f44.sum(f12)} ] [12/8]")
    elif self == f12 and other == f44:
       print(f"[{f12} + {f44} == {f12.minus(f44)} ] [4/8]")
    elif self == f128 and other == f32:
       print(f"[{f128} == {f32} == {f128.requal(f32)} ] [True]")



def main():

print("Wlecome to Fraction Caculator!")
numerator_1 = input("Fraction 1 Numerator: ")
denominator_1 = input("Fraction 1 denominator ")
f12 = Fraction(numerator_1, denominator_1)
numerator_2 = input("Fraction 2 Numerator: ")
denominator_2 = input("Fraction 2 denominator ")
f44 = Fraction(numerator_2, denominator_2)

#for texting parts


operation = print("Please enter the operation +, - , *, //, %, == ")
if operation == "+":
    f12.sum(f44)
elif operation == "-":
    f12.mins(f44)
elif operation == "*":
    f12.times(f44)
elif operation == "//":
    f12.divid(f44)
 #for texting values







if __name__ == "_ _ main _ _ ":
main()
```